# How to rename a git branch named by error "-update"?

Tags: git, branch

I've named by error a branch `-update`. When I try to rename it with `git branch -m -update update` I get the error `error: unknown switch 'u'`.

Is there a way to rename the branch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `git branch -m -- -update update`?

Comment: I've just tried this (as suggested first by Adam as well), it works, thanks!

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the time stamp, you will see that I was in fact 100 seconds ahead of Adam -- the sorting of answers is not in time order, but something like 'most (recent activity + votes + views) first', with some weighting, so you often see the _latest_ answer at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `git checkout -b proper_name`. Then simply go and delete the unwanted branch file in .git/refs/heads.

This is simpler than fiddling around with bash if in doubt of character escaping, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks adymitruk. I've applied Adam's solution as I need the work already done in the branch.

Comment: this keeps the work already done in your branch and does not matter what version of git you use.

Comment: You can use `git update-ref -d refs/heads/-update` to delete ill-named branches. This plumbing command is a better than `rm .git/heads/-update` because it also works if the ref has been packed, and it deletes the associated reflogs.

Comment: Usually during `git gc` (controllable via `gc.packrefs`), but something else could do at any time with `git pack-refs --all`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should be able to use double hyphens before your names to end flag processing, but doing that to try and create a branch called `-update` doesn't work for me:

```
$ git branch -- -update
fatal: '-update' is not a valid branch name.
```

If your version of git is allowing it, you can try `git branch -m -- -update update`

Comment: It may or may not work depending on the version of git you use. No guarantees with msysgit on windows either.

Comment: In git, often `--` separates commit arguments (including branch names) from file arguments (for example for `diff`, `checkout`). This may be the reason it does not work everywhere.